# Which name for a "smart" dictionary (hashtable)?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, naming-conventions

I'm looking for a good name for a custom dictionary which automatically initializes the value for a requested key if it doesn't exist, using a delegate. The indexer implementation should help understand what it does :

```
    public V this[K key]
    {
        get
        {
            V value;
            if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                value = _defaultValueGenerator(key);
                _dictionary[key] = value;
            }
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            _dictionary[key] = value;
        }
    }
```

My problem is not about the code, which works fine, but I can't seem to find a proper name for this class... I thought about `AutoInitDictionary`, but it doesn't sound right, and doesn't really conveys the idea that "all keys can be assumed to exist".

How would you name such a class ? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

---

PS: an example of how it could be used :

```
var charFrequencies = new AutoInitDictionary<char, int>(key => 0);
foreach(char c in text)
    charFrequencies[c]++;
```

Comment: @Eric: well, I don't think so... but thanks for the good laugh anyway ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has exactly this kind of dictionary, and they call it a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: I like it... to follow the .NET naming style, it would be something like `DefaultDictionary`. The only thing that bothers me is that it sounds like it is "the default kind of dictionary"...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest FactoryDictionary option.

Comment: Not bad... however it describes the implementation, rather than the behavior

Answer (score 1):

What about `VirtualDictionary`?

> vir·tu·al (vûr'chōō-əl):
>
> Existing or resulting in essence or effect though not in actual fact, form
>
> Existing in the mind, especially as a product of the imagination
>
> Being such in power, force, or effect, though not actually or expressly such
>
> Temporarily simulated or extended by computer software

All 4 definitions somewhat relate to your implementation.

EDIT: Even `DynamicDictionary` will be good.

Answer (score 0):

How about **SmartDictionary**? I thought your subject was good enough. ;)

Answer (score 0):

FullDictionary ?